# Problem with tapestry5 syntax checking in Eclipse 3.7 on OSX 10.5.8

Tags: eclipse, macos, syntax, tapestry

I've been working with Tapestry5 in Eclipse 3.7 for a week or so, and can't get syntax checking to work correctly on OSX. I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

I found this link that explains what to do:

http://wiki.apache.org/tapestry/Tapestry5JSPEditorEclipse

This works perfectly in Eclipse 3.7 on Windows Vista Ultimate (my home workstation). However on OSX (my laptop), the hilighting itself works, yet Eclipse tells me there are errors in the code.

Here's an image of what it looks like:

[screenshot](http://www.georgeludwigtech.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/eclipse-errors.png)

Eclipse tells me the following:

- The function message:greeting is undefined
- javax.servlet.jsp.JspException cannot be resolved to a type
- javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext cannot be resolved to a type

Since I am using Eclipse EE for Web Development, I would have thought I have the complete javax library. Naturally, I ran mvn eclipse:eclipse on the project to download all required libraries.

I'm at a loss for what I'm doing wrong...the Windows setup was effortless!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this last night, it turns out it was just a hiccup with the Eclipse project. After deleting the project (and contents on disk) and checking it out again, running mvn eclipse:eclipse, everything was good.

I love Eclipse, but some times you have to deal with issues like this...